# Dijkstras Algorithm and interpreting this graph

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

We are given the following weighted graph:

\begin{matrix}
  &  A & B & C & D & E & F \\
  A & - & 5  & 8&3&4&9 \\
  B &  &- &6&1&5&4 \\
  C & && - & 3&9&2\\
  D&&&&-&4&6\\
  E&&&&&-&3\\
  \end{matrix}

and we are asked to find the shortest path from A to F. Using Dijkstras algorithm, this can be calculated to ADCF, which is the "correct" answer. 
However, upon inspection, and drawing the graph as I interpret it, it seems like there is a shorter path available in just going AEF (The path above would have a total of 3 + 3 + 2 'weights' and the latter only having 4 + 3). I assume that I have made some sort of mistake in interpreting the graph, or in drawing it, but I can't seem to find it.

My interpretation is: The row marked 'A' is the list of neighbors to A, and their respective weights. I.e A is connected to each of B,D,C,D,E and F. B in turn, is connected to C,D,E and F through the weights given in row 'B' and also to A of course, being mirror symmetric around the '-' line. Basically just a standard matrix representation of a graph with added weights to each edge.

But like I said, that would mean that there is a way from A to E to F that is shorter than the one Dijkstras algorithm produces. Ideas?

EDIT: Redoing the algorithm on my sketch of the graph, I found that it indeed gave the route AEF as the shortest route. However, this then differs from the books answer of ADCF. Here is how I apply the algorithm, using a tabular method:

Start at A, and make a list of the shortest paths to each node. Choose the shortest one and mark it. Write down the edge formed in order to adjoin this one to a tree with root A. Start from the marked one, and make a list of all the shortest routes from A to all of the neighbors of A, and all the ones reachable via the nodes marked so far. Repeat. When

\begin{matrix}
  &  A & B & C & D & E & F \\
  A & - & 5  & 8&(3) &4&9 \\
  D &  &4 &6&-&(4)&9 \\
  E & &(4)& 6 & -&-&7\\
  B &-&-&(6)&-&-&7\\
  C&-&-&-&-&-&(7)\\
  \end{matrix}

The edges formed are {A,D},{A,E},{D,B},{D,C},{E,F}, and we can see that A connects to E, which connects to F. My original mistake was that I mislabeled (repeatedly it seems...) the last edge as {C,F}. But this again disagrees  with the answer in the book, so I just want to make sure haven't misunderstood anything.

Comment: Obviously, you have failed to implement the algorithm correctly. Why not write out all the steps you used, and we'll see where you went wrong?

Comment: The chart doesn't imply that all nodes are connected.  The value A-F as 9 could mean that the fastest calculated path (thus far at least) is from ABF.  If the chart is consistent, then AF is the shortest calculated path leading from A to F, which may or may not be a direct route.

Comment: @gerry I have updated the question to include my solution. After review, it does give me AEF as the shortest path but that would disagree with the answer in the book. Before I call 'errata' I would however like to be sure that I haven't made a big misinterpretation!

Comment: What you've done looks right. So if all else is as you say it is, there's a mistake in the book.